# Complete app uninstaller for free?

Tags: macos, applications, software-recommendation

Is there any way I can completely uninstall an app for free?
I know there are apps that delete the app and the leftovers but none seem to be free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/), it's free, deletes Mac apps and remove any of its related files. To use it, just drag and drop the app you want to remove onto AppCleaners window.

Comment: if it didn't need an admin password to install, it didn't leave anything 'dangerous' in the system, only some prefs files that will make no difference once you throw the app in the trash.

Answer (score 0):

someone, not I, might also be able to post the terminal command to find all files associated with an application. AppCleaner is better than some of the others but it too will sometimes leave kernel extensions and daemons etc behind.